# how we can save database created in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite

I am new to database. I am trying to create a database and table in it.
but unable to save and open again after exiting from sqlite.
I am using  sqlite3 3.6.20 on centOS, when i will enter following command

```
.save ex1.db or .open ex1.db
```

it will print following error message.

```
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "save". Enter ".help" for help
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "open". Enter ".help" for help
```

and when Print .help
it wont show any command related to save and open existing database.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I am trying to create a database and table in it. but unable to save and open again after exiting from sqlite.

You don't need to save. Each transaction writes to disk. (More or less.)

To create the database "test.sl3", you can do this. (From the command line. Programs work about the same way.)

```
$ sqlite3 test.sl3
SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table test (test_id integer primary key);
sqlite> insert into test values (1);
sqlite> select * from test;
1
.quit
```

No `.save`. Now load the database again.

```
$ sqlite3 test.sl3
SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from test;
1
```

The data is still there.

Answer (score 6):

You're supposed to provide a filename as an argument for the .save command, e.g.:

```
sqlite> .save ex1.db
```

docs: http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: yup,I am giving name of database, even though that prints error msg.

Answer (score 5):

as Mike pointed out in his answer, you should provide a file name to put the database in.

If you did a lot of work and you did not provide a file name up front and you work in a version in which the `.save` command is not yet available (you quote that `sqlite3 3.6.20` does not know it and I also do not see it in `sqlite3 version 3.8.2`) you can use the `.backup` command

```
sqlite> .help
[...]
.backup ?DB? FILE      Backup DB (default "main") to FILE

$ sqlite3
[...]
sqlite> create table mytable ( column1 text, column2 integer );
sqlite> insert into mytable values ( 'ENTRY1', 1 );  
sqlite> insert into mytable values ( 'ENTRY2', 2 ); 
sqlite> .backup main  temp.db
sqlite> .quit

$ sqlite3 temp.db
[...]
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE mytable ( column1 text, column2 integer );
sqlite> select * from mytable;
column1     column2   
----------  ----------
ENTRY1      1         
ENTRY2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sqlite3 ex1.db` to open your database. After that, all queries will take effect in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

I am in VS Code using the SQLite extension by alexcvzz.

When I use a relative path, I get an error.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1, "Hello");

.save ex1.db
```

When I use an absolute path, it works.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1, "Hello");

.save /Users/zacharyargentin/databases/ex1.db
```

Note: In the VS Code extension you have to choose a database before you run the query, so I chose the :memory: database, which is the default in-memory database. This database deletes itself as soon as you close the connection (so if you want to keep it, you have to save it like I did in the example above).