# How to implement foreign key constraints of sqlite in java application?

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to create an application in java consisting of SQLite as a back-end DB. I have choosen SQLite because with other relatinal DBs we cannot create .exe file of our project. My Questions are :-

1) How to implement foreign key constraints of sqlite in java application?
 2) When I create any Database and table in SQLite3 it just get created for    only that instance of time, when I start my computer second time and try to open that previously created database and table, it doesn't get opened.

So please help me with the issue...

(Thank you in advance !!).

Comment: [Quick search "sqlite foreign key constraint"](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html); Note foreign key constraints were added in 3.6.19. [Relevant question on saving sqlite databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024810/how-we-can-save-database-created-in-sqlite3)

Comment: commit the transaction , it will persist the data.